# Rake task in Thor script ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, thor

i'm in the process of building an installer.
And with that, i want to migrate the database somehow.
I'm making my installer in Rails 3 using Thor.

So something like(in the command line)

```
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rails generator api actually provides a rake method, and is very easy to use. So for example your generator file could look like:

```
class RakeTestGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  def rake_db
    rake("db:migrate")
  end
end
```

You could then execute this within your rails app by running the following.

```
rails g rake_test
```

Which would be the equivalent of running "rake db:migrate" in the command line. Note that all publicly defined methods in a rails generator are executed when the command is run.

*Additional info:* The rake method is provided by Rails::Generators::Actions module and is available by the Rails::Generators::Base class. See the [Official Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Generators/Actions.html#method-i-rake) for more information.